# Add custom code to right sidebar on advanced search result page

Tags: magento

I'm trying to show custom (dynamic) text in the right sidebar of the advanced search result page.

I can add a static block -- but that won't help in this case.

I've added the code to the product view page -- and it works fine.

see http://www.ktav.com/index.php/ktav/philosophy/orthodox-forum/the-next-generation-of-modern-orthodoxy.html for an example.

I need something similar on the Advanced search results.

Any suggestions HOW I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: how did you add this on product page?

Comment: I edited product/view.phtml -- added the code below the
<?php if(isset($section['related'])) if block

IN order to show all of the related products in the series (by getting the contents of the category)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just edit that static block content and at the bottom add the following code

{{block type="core/template" template="catalogsearch/advanced/resultpagelinks.phtml"}}

Create catalogsearch/advanced/resultpagelinks.phtml file in the correct path and produce your dynamic links in this. In this file, if you need you will get the search results block data by calling Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('catalogsearch/advanced_result')

For example

$resultsBlock = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('catalogsearch/advanced_result');
var_dump($resultsBlock->getResultCount());//Return the search results count

So you can create dynamic links according to the search results.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll try it Sunday morning and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know which page to edit, then follow this:

To turn on template path hints in Magento:

```
1.log into the magento back-end admin

2.Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu

3.Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED

4.Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.

5.Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.
```

**Remember to clear your cache.**

For more info [**Clicke here**](http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints).

If this not help you, the `right side bar` page should be:
**\app\design\frontend\yourtemplate\yourtemplate\template\catalog\navigation\left_nav.phtml**

Here you can write your custom text.

Comment: I know what file to edit (I think -- results.phtml). I've already made changes to the actual results page -- it's how to add text to the right sidebar/column that I can't figure out.

Comment: @Akiva, can I see the results page? do u have a url?

Comment: @ManafPM the URL for a product is
http://www.ktav.com/index.php/ktav/philosophy/orthodox-forum/the-next-generation-of-modern-orthodoxy.html

Comment: @Akiva, not the product page. I just like to see the search results page. You told that you have already made changes to the actual results page except the text. Could you please get me the url to that page?

Comment: @ManafPM If you click on the Orthodox Forum link at the top of the product page it takes you to an advanced search result page -- modified to show additional information. In the right column/sidebar at the top are 2 .. -- that's from a static block. I want to put links under that (similar to the links on the side of the product page)

Comment: @ManafPM or just go to http://www.ktav.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?seriesname=Orthodox%20Forum

Comment: @ManafPM Here is my results.html -- I want the TEST2 to be in the right sidebar...obviously I'm misunderstanding something... :


<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>  
<?php if($this->getResultCount()): ?>  
...  
<?php endif; ?>  
<?php $this->getSearchCriterias(); ?>  

<?php echo 'TEST1'; ?>   
 <div class="product-secondary-column <?php echo 'grid12-12'; ?> custom-sidebar-right">  
       `      <div class="inner">`
           `       <?php echo 'TEST2'; ?> `
`  </div>`
`</div>`

Comment: I think you should edit that static block which you are used to display '..' . and at the bottom add your links as html via the static block editor

Comment: @ManafPM I need to generate the links dynamically -- depending on the results of the Advanced Search -- so static blocks don't help (unless there's a way to dynamically modify the contents of a static block?)